# How to export animations to use in an Android app

Tags: animation, export

I have made some animations in Blender, use the native Android SDK to build apps and would like to export the animations from Blender, so I can use in my app.

I'm talking about exporting the actual animation, not about rendering it; for example: I have a box that blows up, in Blender - I want it to blow up in the app when an event occurs.

How can I export a Blender animation to be used in an Android app?

Comment: You mean render the animation and play the video in the app, or do you want to export the 3D scene to your SDK?

Comment: Yes. I want to use the 3D scene. For example, I have a box that blows up. I want it to blow up in the android app when a event occurs.

Comment: The accepted answer while it might work is not ideal. See my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is to export a Wavefront Obj sequence; This will give you a sequence of files, where each represents the positions of each vertex, at the given time. This format is probably the best, since it's very simple and uses ASCII.

To do this in Blender, after you have your animation ready, go to the `Header`, then `File`, the `Export` and finally `Wavefront (.obj)`. The interface layout will change and show you the *File Browser*, where you can select the output path and name. Before clicking `Export`, you need to go to the panel on the left and in the subsection `Export OBJ` check `Animation`.

[image]

Comment: Exporting to an obj sequence is a terrible idea even for animation with  few frames. Not only will there be several files but it's quite costly to load and go through these. Never exported animation for use on mobile before but I would be surprised if some format that supports animation doesn't work there or check out threejs.

Comment: @iKlsR There are definitely better ways, such as using Blender's animation player engine thing (technical term); but an answer explaining this would be off topic on this site - or would say "Go to file, chose export and the some format; then copy the relevant code into your app, from Blender's git.".

Comment: What? You don't need to modify any code to export animation and what does blenderplayer have to do with exporting animation? It launches games.

Comment: @iKlsR You need to _import it_ - and it's much more complex than using an .obj sequence. An I mean the animation player not the game player